# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.models' has no attribute 'experimental'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to use the `tf.keras.models.experimental.SharpnessAwareMinimization` class from tf-nightly. I installed tf-nightly with `pip install tf-nightly` and tf-nightly-gpu with `pip install tf-nightly-gpu`.

Then, I import tensorflow with `import tensorflow as tf`. May I know how to proceed from here?

`tf.__vesion__` is 2.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I am able to run this code and import `SharpnessAwareMinimization` api successfully and it shows below tensorflow version:

```
!pip install tf_nightly

import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__

from tensorflow.keras.models.experimental import SharpnessAwareMinimization
```

Output: (I got the same output in `Google colab` and `Jupyter notebook`)

```
2.11.0-dev20220806
```

Please run this code again `!pip install tf_nightly` and retstart the kernel (runtime). Check again the tensorflow version and let us know if the issue still persists.